# Random walk and Poisson process

Tags: probability, random-variable, binomial-distribution, poisson-process, random-walk

(1) A point is chosen at random in a circle with center at the origin and radius R. That point is taken as the center of a circle with radius X where X is a random variable having density f. Find the probability p that the random circle contains the origin.

(2) Suppose n points are independently and uniformly chosen in the circle with center at the origin and radius R. Each point is taken as the center of a random circle whose radius has density f . Find in terms of p of Exercise 1, the probability that exactly k circles contain the origin.

(3) Find the answer to Exercise 2 if the n points are replaced with a random number N of points having a Poisson distribution with mean $\pi R^2$

**My attempt to answer question (1):**

$p = 2 \displaystyle\int_0^\infty\left(\displaystyle\int_0^R X f( X + Z )dX \right) dZ$

But author's answer is $$ p=\frac{2}{R^2} \displaystyle\int_0^\infty\left(\displaystyle\int_0^R X f( X + Z )dX \right) dZ$$

**My answer to (b):**$\binom{n}{k}p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$ which matches with author's answer.

**My answer to (c):** $\frac{(\pi R^2 p)^K}{K!} e^{-\pi R^2 p}$ which also matches with the answer provided by the authors(Hoel,Port,Stone)

Now, what is wrong with my answer to question(1)?

Is my answer to question(1) correct? or author's answer is correct.

Any member of stats.stackexchange knowing correct answer to question(1) may reply.
Any math help will be accepted.

Comment: The probability $p$ needs to be a dimensionless quantity so your answer can not be correct.

Comment: @JarleTufto, So, $\frac{2}{R^2}\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \displaystyle\int_0^R X f(X+Z) dX dZ = 1$

Comment: No, the expression given by the author is not equal to one, but its _dimension_ is.